# Cron Job With Altering Behavior Depending on Hour

Tags: cron

Is it possible to execute a Cron job such that between certain hours, it executes every 30 minutes, but other hours, only every 1 hour?

I was unable to figure this out using my basic Cron abilities.

Comment: */30 12-14 * * * ...
    0 15-18 * * * ...

Comment: Paul, can you elaborate on how this would work?

Comment: Sorry, I could not figure out how to properly format the code in a comment... In my previous post, it's actually two lines, one for each case. The first one `*/30 12-14 * * * ...` would run your job every 30 minutes between 12:00 and 14:30, the second one `0 15-18 * * * ...` only at the full hour between 15:00 and 18:00

Comment: Another possibility would be `0,30 15-18 * * * ...`